# In Amazon Redshift though I have specified service_date column as Date datatype but when I am taking date in IN operator it working with quotes only

Tags: amazon-redshift

```
select * 
from nsclc_thought_spot 
where patientid = 11000001 
  and service_date in ('2019-07-08', '2019-07-10')
order by patientid, service_date
```

is returning the results properly

But this is not working as expected:

```
select * 
from nsclc_thought_spot 
where patientid = 11000001 
  and service_date in (2019-07-08, 2019-07-10)
order by patientid, service_date
```

This query is not returning results.

If I have defined `service_date` column as `date`, then why do I have to pass the values in quotes inside `IN` operator in redshift?

Answer (score 2):

Because 2019-07-08 means the integer 2019 minus the integer 7 minus the integer 8 which equals the integer 2004.  Without quotes in SQL numbers are seen as numeric values.  To be interpreted as something else you need to quote them (which is a text value) and then they need to be cast to the data type needed.  In this case '2019-07-08' is a text value but Redshift will implicitly cast this to a date to make the comparison to the column data "service_date".

If you want to do this explicitly you can add the casting to the values - ... service_date IN ('2019-07-08'::date,'2019-07-10'::date) ... - which might make things clearer for you.